# How do I set XBMC as the default media player?

Tags: xbmc

I've recently started using xbmc and i love it. The only thing is i cant find a way of setting it as the default media player.

It just does not show up on the default list. I hope someone out there help on this.

Answer (score 1):

xbmc is a media center not a media player.
You must start xbmc first to open a file with-in
I agree it is a great media center probebly the best but i would use Mplayer if you  want to just click on files to open them

Answer (score 1):

This will add a new menu entry via a desktop file, XBMC-sendto, which will open XBMC or give it focus and open the media file. It works with audio, video and picture files that are local or on network shares (I've only tested with smb shares). This requires the program wmctrl to be installed and JSON-RPC (the webserver) to be enabled in XBMC/KODI.

The zip file contains two files. The kde-send-to-xbmc.sh file can be placed anywhere you like (don't forget to make it executable) and the xbmc-send2.desktop file needs to be placed in ~/.local/share/applications/. Then edit xbmc-send2.desktop and update the Exec= line to reflect where you put the sh file. If json-rpc uses a non-standard port or you want to send content to a remote xbmc host you need to edit kde-send-to-xbmc.sh. You may need to restart you desktop environment, although this was not necessary in KDE4. Now you will be able to open media files with XBMC directly from the desktop (you'll probably need to set XBMC-sendto as the default program for a particular file type).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22410524/xbmc/xbmc-file-associations-0.0.1.zip

I have only tested this with KDE, I would like to hear if it works (or doesnt) with other DE's. Also the file types are wholesale borrowed from VLC/GIMP's dektop files, let me know if any are missing or incorrect.

Link to XBMC/KODI forum page: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=201285

EDIT: Fixed Dropbox link.